# Libraries for image viewing with zoom for react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there a good libraries for RN for image viewing with good zoom on big images?

I have tried many libraries for my goal but all of them have bad zoom on big images
(react-native-image-gallery, react-native-image-zoom-viewer, react-native-image-viewing and etc)

Hope for help, thanks

Comment: I've heard that RN skia does good zooming on images but i've never tried it

Answer (score 0):

react native image zooming/viewer is pain of ass, I saw many lib make a `<Modal>` for each `<Touchable><Image/></Touchable>`, so I require more more views. Or may I had not find another good library.( Can someone guide me for perfect lib)

With `FlatList` or `GridView` = many many images, It's will took more performance.

My solution:
Write native module to open new screen to view images. Alse write case multi image, loadmore,... all you need is just pass imageUrl list + page... etc.

For simple case I am using `LightBox` for IOS, `StaffconImageViewer` for android

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable zoom functionality for images in React Native without using external libraries, you can create a custom solution with React Native's built-in components and gestures. Here's a simple example:

```
import React, { useRef, createRef } from "react";
import { Animated, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import {
    GestureHandlerRootView,
    PanGestureHandler,
    PinchGestureHandler,
    State
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const ZoomableImage = ({ uri }) => {
    const pinchRef = createRef();
    const panRef = createRef();

    const baseScale = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
    const pinchScale = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
    const scale = useRef(Animated.multiply(baseScale, pinchScale)).current;
    let lastScale = 1;

    const onPinchGestureEvent = Animated.event(
        [
            {
                nativeEvent: {
                    scale: pinchScale
                }
            }
        ],
        { useNativeDriver: true }
    );

    const handlePinchStateChange = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
        if (nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
            lastScale *= nativeEvent.scale;
            baseScale.setValue(lastScale);
            pinchScale.setValue(1);
        }
    };

    const translateX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const translateY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    let lastOffset = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    const onPanEvent = Animated.event(
        [
            {
                nativeEvent: {
                    translationX: translateX,
                    translationY: translateY
                }
            }
        ],
        { useNativeDriver: true }
    );

    const handlePanStateChange = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
        if (nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
            lastOffset.x += nativeEvent.translationX;
            lastOffset.y += nativeEvent.translationY;

            translateX.setOffset(lastOffset.x);
            translateX.setValue(0);
            translateY.setOffset(lastOffset.y);
            translateY.setValue(0);
        }
    };

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <PanGestureHandler
                ref={panRef}
                onGestureEvent={onPanEvent}
                onHandlerStateChange={handlePanStateChange}
                shouldCancelWhenOutside
            >
                <Animated.View style={[styles.wrapper]}>
                    <PinchGestureHandler
                        ref={pinchRef}
                        simultaneousHandlers={panRef}
                        onGestureEvent={onPinchGestureEvent}
                        onHandlerStateChange={handlePinchStateChange}
                    >
                        <Animated.View style={styles.imageContainer} collapsable={false}>
                            <Animated.Image
                                style={[
                                    styles.pinchableImage,
                                    {
                                        transform: [
                                            { scale: scale },
                                            { translateX },
                                            { translateY }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]}
                                source={{ uri }}
                            />
                        </Animated.View>
                    </PinchGestureHandler>
                </Animated.View>
            </PanGestureHandler>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
};

export default ZoomableImage;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },
    imageContainer: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        overflow: "scroll"
    },
    pinchableImage: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        resizeMode: "contain",
    },
    wrapper: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```